# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages Site Very Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I created my WebSite on Asp.Net Core and I hosted it on SmarterAsp.Net

http://greensaucegames.com/

I don't know what the problem is, if it was something I did, or if the hosting server is slow.

But the site is very slow, sometimes it doesn't even open the page I just clicked, the one from nowhere it reloads.

Does anyone know a way for me to try to diagnose what may be making it so slow and intermittent? How do you do it? Or some advice on how can I improve the speed?

Are Razor Pages really slow? Should I use something else?

I do use Blazor for the Admin Area, can this be interfering with the rest of the site?

Comment: SmarterAsp will turn off the pool if there is no request for 15 mins. so the initial request will take much more time. you can check with them wither its some thing like that. for me they suggested to create task run for every 15 mins. you can check your db with sql profiler.

Comment: if still not able to find out i suggest something like this "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/measuring-and-reporting-the-response-time-of-an-asp-net-core-api/" and log the time to be sure.

Comment: There can be several possible issues that might cause a site to be slow. Every site is unique. Some solutions to speed up may work for one site but not another. A good place to start would be https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I ran a quick test for your site and it ranked 14/100 for desktop and 4/100 for mobile. 
From the looks of it, the assets being served are too large. try to reduce the size of the images.
Do a quick test yourself and analyze the results. Another article you might find helpful is https://moz.com/learn/seo/page-speed

Comment: while not your initial problem most likely, your webpage homepage is 20.7MB (which represents 40.9MB uncompressed), which takes 20 seconds to fully transfer and 9.5s to Load.

Comment: also, Razor pages should be very fast, and yes, you have some blazor stuff leaking into the home page, it's trying to establish a websocket.

Answer (score 2):

Because your hosting subscription plan is very cheap. Use a high resources server will see acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1):

I went to SmarterAsp.Net's homepage, and even ***IT*** loaded very slowly.  I clicked on their "Why Us" link and watched in horror as a medium-sized image scanned in over about 15 seconds.  The words "total garbage" immediately came to mind.

Then I tried to open one of your asset images in a new browser tab.  Just the image itself, which is not a large one, took like 20 seconds to load.

**Conclusion-- 100% chance that the shared hosting you have is the problem.**

When I first put up a real business website, it took me quite a while to realize that shared hosting is a no-go.  **Even if** the site works great at first, new users will come to that host, and soon enough you'll be stuck in glue again.  Upgrading to "premium" packages and so on didn't help either.

Then I opened up my wallet, shelled out for an Azure Windows Server VM, and added a couple years to my life thanks to my immediate and total lack of stress.  It's nice when everything just works.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that make your site working slowly. For example

- How effective is your code
- How effective is your SQL query
- Have you optimized your image

If you believe that you have optimized your site, then you need to check your external factors like your hosting provider. You may need to upgrade your plan to higher plan to get more stable server. Their hosting service is cheap but it might impact to your webiste performance. To test it, you can upgrade to higher plan. If your site still working slowly, you may need to find other hosting provider. I personally use Asphostportal.com and I can recommend them if you need .NET Core hosting.